# Generics in POJO - Is this a good practice

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I have a Base Class.

```
@Data
class BaseDocument{
    String id;
    String name;
    //Other fields
}
```

Say I have many classes that extends BaseDocument one below.

```
class NoteDocument extends BaseDocument{
    String description;
    Long lastModifiedDate;
    //etc
}
```

It does not make sense to me to send entire document to UI in some cases. Most of the cases I need only id and name. 
So for every document I have a VO class.

```
@Data
class BaseVO {
    private String id;
    private String name;
}

@Data
class NoteVO extends BaseVO{
    //Nothing here now

}
```

And in NoteDocument I have.

```
public NoteVO getVo(){
        Assert.notNull(getId());
        NoteVO noteVo = new NoteVO();
        noteVo.setName(getName());
        noteVo.setId(getId());
        return noteVo;
    }
```

Now I have to copy this method in all the classes that extends BaseDocument.

Instead, I changed my BaseDocument like below.

```
    @Data
    class BaseDocument<V extends BaseVO>{
        String id;
        String name;

        public V getVo(Class className)  {
            Assert.notNull(getId());
            V vo = null;
            try {
                vo = (V) className.newInstance();
                vo.setName(getName());
                vo.setId(getId());
            } catch (IllegalAccessException|InstantiationException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Assert.notNull(vo);
            return vo;
        }

    }
```

I am new to generics. My first question, is this a good practice. Are there any problems in using reflection to create instance, any performance issues? Is there any better way to do achieve (write less code) this.

*Edit: Suppose I need to display note in UI, Along with note I need to display name of the User who created note. I am using mongodb, when I save the note I also save UserVO in note, which will have user id and name of the user. If I save only user id while saving the note, I will have to do one more query to get the name of user while displaying. I want to avoid this.*

Comment: Yes. java reflection is expensive. can't you write factory to create objects?

Comment: I definitely would not consider this good practice. If you're using reflection to build a simple object, it's a good sign that you need to go back to the drawing board. However, I would consider it fairly unlikely that it's a performance issue, although that really depends on how often you are creating these objects. For me, readability is the important concern here.

What is the purpose of the VO classes anyway? Why not just design a class/interface defining what the UI needs and then just implement that with different document types. Or maybe I misunderstood you.

Comment: @MikkelK. I edited the answer, hope I could convey what is am trying to do.

Comment: I would use composition instead of inheritance to do what you want to do. A `NoteDocument` would contain a `BaseDocument`, and the `BaseDocument` could be used alone if data in `NoteDocument` is not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use reflection; use inheritance and maybe covariant return types instead.  It will be faster, clearer, more precise, and easier to maintain.  You may also find it useful to add methods to populate your VOs incrementally.  I didn't come up with a clean way to apply generics to this situation, but I don't think you need them:

```
class BaseVO {
    String id;
    String name;

    void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

class NoteVO extends BaseVO {
    // ...
}

@Data
class BaseDocument {
    String id;
    String name;
    //Other fields

    protected void populateBaseVO(BaseVO vo) {
        vo.setId(id);
        vo.setName(name);
    }

    public BaseVO getVO() {
        BaseVO vo = new BaseVO();

        populateBaseVO(vo);
        return vo;
    }
}

@Data
class NoteDocument extends BaseDocument {
    String description;
    Long lastModifiedDate;
    // ....

    protected void populateNoteVO(NoteVO vo) {
        populateBaseVO(vo);
        // ...
    }

    public NoteVO getVO() {
        NoteVO vo = new NoteVO();

        populateNoteVO(vo);
        return vo;
    }
}
```